# AngularJS directive scope variable doesnt update after reopening the window

Tags: angularjs, frontend

This question might seem as if it was asked before but I can't find solution anywhere.

I have directive to which i pass array

```
    <div modal-panel 
     array="ctrl.array" >
    </div>
```

and i get it in scope

```
       scope: {
            array: '=',
        },
```

It works all good, updates, etc until I close the form and open it once again.
It just doesn't update.
I tried logging the contents of an array to console and it is just the old array from the time i first opened the form containing that directive. I tired doing things like

```
 $scope.$on('$destroy', () => { 
    $scope.array = null
 });
```

but it just doesnt work. Any ideas appreciated

## edit

I found that the problem exists only in callback that i have to check all checkboxes in ng-table containing that array.

Is there a way to update data in a callback when this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

The directive was'nt rebuilt cause of my spa app and list of callbacks wasn't updated so there was one callback with old reference. I just deleted old callback and added new with actual reference.